# Serving HTML Content

Tags: javascript, html

I'm in need of a way to serve either HTML or links to external webpages. Basically what needs to be done is we will have webpages, and then would like to give a user of our site a URL or piece of javascript to insert into their own page, which will then display our HTML on their page upon load.

Can somebody please guide me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the facility must be provided by the external website.

Comment: I'm sorry; That was twice as vague as my question. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Hmmm. I guess I could simple give them a piece of code (Frame, or IFrame). That should do the trick, til I can come up with a better solution...

Comment: @user what server side platform are you on?

Comment: I'm with Winhost.com. They support both ASP.NET 4.0 and PHP 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you appear to need is the iframe tag.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew B. Are you aware of any problems that may arise out of the use of an IFrame? I.e, do some browsers not support them anymore, or not support them properly?

Comment: iframes are pretty much completely supported by all modern, desktop browsers. Just like many other tags, there are occasional quirks in how they will display in one browser or another. But also keep in mind that you may run into users who have security-related troubles from loading content in multiple sites; over-enthusiastic browser plugins trying to protect against cross-site scripting, for example. But that's going to apply with any appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to pull the content from your site

```
<script src="http://youdomain.com/mycontent.js">
</script>
```

then in your js file use

```
var myhtml ='';

myhtml += "Put your html in here";
document.write(myhtml);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
// JsAdServer.php Copyright(c) 2013 by Phillip S. Smith Enterprises
// ok to use but include my copyright notice in code.

$htmlcontent=file_get_contents($url);
// you may also use curl or any other method to populate $htmlcontent

$jsContent=$htmlcontent;
$jsContent=preg_replace('/>\s+</','><',$jsContent);
$jsContent=str_replace("<hr />",'',$jsContent);// remove if hr's required
$jsContent=str_replace(chr(13),'',$jsContent);
$jsContent=str_replace(chr(10),'',$jsContent);
$jsContent=str_replace("'","\'",$jsContent);
$jsContent=str_replace('a href="','a target="new" rel="nofollow" href="',$jsContent);
print "document.write('$jsContent');";
?>
```

Comment: Advertising isn't permitted.